# How to add a custom language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 7 there is a section to add a custom language

[image]

But in Drupal 8 that section does not exist,

[image]

How can I add my custom language in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is,just open *Language name* select list and  choose  last item **Custom language ...** .

[image: Add custom language in drupal 8]